# How to change row color based on a checkbox status change?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying several codes when editing macro of a checkbox but none seem to have an effect, and I always get `error 424` something about missing object
[image]

so say it's `Checkbox44_OnClick()` I can't use `Checbox44.value` or at all

Any ideas how I can change row color based on a checkbox status?

```
Sub CheckBox44_Click()
    If Checkbox44.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("8:8").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line produced the error?  That code worked for me.

Comment: `Sub CheckBox44_Click()` but `If Checkbox1.Value = True Then`. Maybe `If Checkbox44.Value = True Then`?

Comment: @simoco, sorry that's what I meant to type. Issue is still there =/
Error produced on the second line/if-statement. Maybe I didn't define that checkbox as Checkbox44? not sure how to do it on Mac Excel 2011

Comment: If the event is triggered when you click a checkbox, it means that checkbox is `CheckBox44`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different types of check boxes available in Excel (Form controls, ActiveX controls). It seems that you are using the forms controls check box. Try this code:

```
Sub CheckBox44_Click()
With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("CheckBox44")
  If .Value = xlOn Then
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("8:8").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Make sure that the name of your checkbox is correctly set (check the Name box when the check box is selected):

[image]

Comment: That last part about naming, cleared out the biggest concern. What's the name of the object

Thanks it works now!

P.s. xlOn is like True? then what is False

Answer (score 0):

IF the sheet is password protected then this error appears.

Try the following:

```
Sub CheckBox44_Click()
Sheet1.Unprotect ("Your Password")
    If Checkbox44.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("8:8").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    End If
Sheet1.Protect ("Your Password")
End Sub
```